# curves bounding discs

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, soft-question, perturbation-theory

I'm interested in the following question. Please forgive me if my question is lacking in precision. I'm not a mathematician, and need some help getting started:

If I have a smooth, simple curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma (0)=\gamma (1)$, and I apply a polynomial $p: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ to it, must the image $p \circ \gamma$ bound an immersed disc in $\mathbb{C}$?

A thought: If the above is not true in general, can I perturb $\gamma$ slightly to $\gamma + \epsilon f$ (where $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$) such that $p\circ (\gamma + \epsilon f)$ does bound an immersed disc in $\mathbb{C}$? If I perturbe $\gamma$, I might give it a singularity (a loop, for example). I'm not sure what types of singularities survive under polynomials though. Is there a classification for such stable singularities? I can visualize a loop being stable, but is that it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bound an immersed disc".  Certainly the image of the curve can cross or touch itself in all kinds of ways, and actual *crossings* will be stable under perturbations.  For instance, a figure-eight has a stable self-crossing, and its interior (depending on how you define it) isn't smoothly deformable to a single disc.

Comment: Consider the figure-8 that is upright (lobes in the $\mathrm{i}$ and $-\mathrm{i}$ directions). Under $z^2$, this maps both lobes to the lower half-plane.  Under $z^3$, both are mapped to the upper half plane.  Much hilarity (and self-crossing) can ensue under the action of polynomials and these won't be correctable via perturbation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the polynomial $z^2$ and apply it to any circle centered at zero. The image loop will not bound an immersed disk even after perturbation. 
This means that the resulting map of the circle will not extend to an immersion of the disk.